# How to distinguish laptop with touch screen from tablet/smartphone with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, touchscreen

I searched [stackoverflow](https://www.google.bg/search?client=ubuntu&hs=mFo&q=how%20to%20distinguish%20laptop%20with%20touchscreen%20and%20tablet%20javascript&oq=how%20to%20distinguish%20laptop%20with%20touchscreen%20and%20tablet%20javasc&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i21k1.98065.102620.0.103277.23.19.4.0.0.0.138.1823.10j8.18.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.13.1283...33i160k1.yp_j7PTUut8) for this and there are many good answers how to detect tablet/phone with touchscreen. However how can I detect and distinguish a laptop with a touchscreen from the mobile devices?

Comment: What's the difference between laptops and mobile devices?

Comment: The problem is that the laptops with touch screens are detected as mobile device.

Comment: But what is the difference? Why do you need to make a difference between a laptop touchscreen and a phone/tablet touchscreen?

Comment: Because the website that I'm supporting has a chat that opens and has a logic that for phones/tablets it resizes the chat window at max resolution because for better UI. However for laptops with touch screens I don't want this window to be resized at max resolution.
So now I need to know if it mobile device with touch screen or a computer with touch.

Comment: In that case you won't benefit anything by knowing if the device is a mobile or a laptop. Use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) to change the layout according to the screen size.